# A property involving two commuting 3-by-3 matrices with non-negative entries

Tags: calculus, matrices, matrix-calculus, sagemath, symbolic-computation

Consider real numbers $m,n,p,q\ge 0$ and the following two matrices 
$$M_1= \left(\begin{matrix} 0&0&1\\0&m&n\\1&n&q \end{matrix} \right), \ \ M_2= \left(\begin{matrix} 0&1&0\\1&p&m\\0&m&n \end{matrix} \right).$$
Let $\chi_i$ be the characteristic polynomials of $M_i$, then:
$$\chi_1(x) = -(x^3-(q+m)x^2+(qm-1-n^2)x+m)$$
$$\chi_2(x) = -(x^3-(p+n)x^2+(pn-1-m^2)x+n)$$
Consider the case where these matrices commute, which is equivalent to $$(\star)\qquad m^2 + n^2 = mq +np + 1.$$

*Remark*: The relation $(\star)$ and the polynomials $\chi_i$ already appeared in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3384478/84284) of [Max Alekseyev](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/147470/max-alekseyev).

Let us assume that $m \le n$. Then the above equation forces $n>0$.
Then we can take $p=(m^2 + n^2 - mq - 1)/n$.

Then, these matrices are self-adjoint and commuting, so simultaneously diagonalizable. Thus, there is an invertible matrix $P$ and (real) eigenvalues  $\alpha_i, \beta_i, \gamma_i$ (the roots of $\chi_i$) such that:

$$P^{-1}M_iP= \left(\begin{matrix} \alpha_i&0&0\\0&\beta_i&0\\0&0&\gamma_i \end{matrix} \right)$$
By positivity $\max(\alpha_i, \beta_i, \gamma_i) = \Vert M_i \Vert$. Let us assume that $\Vert M_i \Vert = \gamma_i$.

We can also assume (up to permutation) that $\alpha_1 = min(\alpha_1, \beta_1, \alpha_2, \beta_2)$.

**Question**: For which $(m,n,q)$ we have $\frac{\alpha_1^3}{\gamma_1} + \frac{\alpha_2^3}{\gamma_2} + 1 <0$ ?

---

*Investigation*

I used SageMath to make some computation when $q=0$, and it *seems* that if $m < n$ then the expected property holds.

Just with $(m,n,q) = (1,n,0)$, SageMath provides complicated formula for $\alpha_i, \beta_i, \gamma_i$:

$\alpha_1 = -\frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{2})^{2/3}(3n^2 + 4)\zeta u^{-1/3} - \frac{1}{6}(\frac{1}{2})^{1/3}u^{1/3} \overline{\zeta}  + 1/3$

$\beta_1 = -\frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{2})^{2/3}(3n^2 + 4) \overline{\zeta} u^{-1/3} - \frac{1}{6}(\frac{1}{2})^{1/3}u^{1/3}\zeta  + 1/3$

$\gamma_1 = \frac{2}{3}(\frac{1}{2})^{2/3}(3n^2 + 4)u^{-1/3} + \frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{2})^{1/3}u^{1/3} + 1/3$

$\alpha_2= -\frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{2})^{2/3}(n^2 + 6) \overline{\zeta} v^{-1/3} - \frac{1}{6}(\frac{1}{2})^{1/3}v^{1/3}\zeta  + \frac{2}{3}n$

$\beta_2= -\frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{2})^{2/3}(n^2 + 6)\zeta v^{-1/3} - \frac{1}{6}(\frac{1}{2})^{1/3}v^{1/3} \overline{\zeta}  + \frac{2}{3}n$

$\gamma_2= \frac{2}{3}(\frac{1}{2})^{2/3}(n^2 + 6)v^{-1/3} + \frac{2}{3}n + \frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{2})^{1/3}v^{1/3}$

with $\zeta = (i\sqrt{3} + 1)$, $u = 9n^2 + 9in(\frac{4}{3}n^4 + \frac{13}{3}n^2 + \frac{32}{3})^{1/2} - 16$ and $v = 16n^3 - 18(n^2 - 2)n - 27n + 9i(\frac{4}{3}n^4 + \frac{13}{3}n^2 + \frac{32}{3})^{1/2}$.

We observe with a computer and large $n$ that $\frac{1}{n}(\frac{\alpha_1(n)^3}{\gamma_1(n)} + \frac{\alpha_2(n)^3}{\gamma_2(n)} + 1) \to -2$

*Example*: for $n=2$ we have 
$$\left(\begin{matrix} \alpha_1 & \beta_1 & \gamma_1\\ \alpha_2 & \beta_2 & \gamma_2 \end{matrix} \right) \simeq \left(\begin{matrix} -1.903211925911 & 0.1939365664746 & 2.709275359436 \\ 1.311107817465 & -0.4811943040920 & 3.170086486626 \end{matrix} \right)$$ and $\frac{\alpha_1(n)^3}{\gamma_1(n)} + \frac{\alpha_2(n)^3}{\gamma_2(n)} + 1 \simeq -0.83357599939<0.$

If we plot for $n=2,3,\dots, 50$, we get

[image]

Now it seems complicated to use such formulas (at least by hand) to answer the question.

Comment: Is $\alpha_2=\min(\alpha_2,\beta_2)$?

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: No, see the numerical values I just added for $(m,n,q) = (1,2,0)$.

Comment: Then I do not understand the distinction between $\alpha_2$ and $\beta_2$ - which is which?

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: $α_i,β_i$ and $γ_i$ are the eigenvalues of $M_i$. If we diagonalize one matrix, then the eigenvalues can appear (in the diagonal) in any order, but if we diagonalize two matrices *simultaneously* (when it is possible, and it is here) then the choice of an order for the eigenvalues of the first matrix forces the order for the second (when the eigenvalues are of multiplicity one, which is true here).

Comment: In the post I assumed that the $\Vert M_i \Vert$-eigenspace of $M_i$ is the same for $i=1$ and $i=2$ (in order to be able to take $\gamma_i = \Vert M_i \Vert$) but it requires a proof.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Is that always the case that $\beta_2\le\alpha_2$?

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: $\alpha_1\beta_1\gamma_1=-n \le 0$ and $\alpha_2\beta_2\gamma_2=-m \le 0$, $\gamma_i = \Vert M_i \Vert > 0$, so if $n,m \neq 0$ then $\alpha_1<0$. If $\alpha_2 \le \beta_2$ then $\alpha_2<0$ also and the property holds. So we can reduce to the case $\beta_2 \le \alpha_2$, and in practice (computation on examples), I always got this case, so perhaps it is always true.

Comment: Moreover, by relation $(\star)$, we cannot have $(m,n) = (0,0)$, and we reduced to the case $m \le n$, so $n>0$.  Completing my previous comment, the case $m=0$ should be consider apart.

Comment: Under the assumption $\beta_2 \leq \alpha_2$, my earlier argument implies that the zeros of $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$ are connected by $\gamma_2 = \frac{n\gamma_1}{\gamma_1-m}$, $\beta_2 = \frac{n\beta_1}{\beta_1-m}$, and $\alpha_2 = \frac{n\alpha_1}{\alpha_1-m}$. So, the expression is question can be reduced to one involving only zeros of $\chi_1$.

Comment: The expression would become $$\frac{\alpha_1^3}{\gamma_1}( 1 + \frac{n^2(\gamma_1-m)}{(\alpha_1-m)^3}) + 1$$

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: the property does not hold for all $m,n,q \ge 0$; for example I checked with my computer that it does not hold for $(m,n,q) = (n,n,n-1)$ for $n=1,\dots, 50$. The problem is to classify for which $(m,n,q)$ the property holds.

Comment: More precisely, it appears numerically by computer that for $m\le n$, $n$ large and $q=m-1$,  then $\alpha_1(m,n) \sim -(n-m)-1/2$, $\alpha_2(m,n) \sim (n-m)+m/(2n)$, $\gamma_1(m,n) \sim m+n-1/2$ and $\gamma_2(m,n) \sim m+n+m/(2n)$, so that $\frac{\alpha_1(m,n)^3}{\gamma_1(m,n)} + \frac{\alpha_2(m,n)^3}{\gamma_2(m,n)} + 1 \sim 1 - 2\frac{(n-m)^3}{n(n+m)} = 1-2m\frac{(k-1)^3}{k(k+1)}$ with $k=n/m$. Then if $k=1$ we get a positive expression, if $1<k<2$, it is negative for $m$ large enough, and if $k\ge 2$, it is always negative.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a necessary condition: $\chi_1(-m^{1/3}) <0$.

Indeed, since. $\alpha_2>0$, we have
$$\frac{\alpha_1^3}{\gamma_1} + 1 < \frac{\alpha_1^3}{\gamma_1} + \frac{\alpha_2^3}{\gamma_2} + 1 <0,$$
implying that $\alpha_1^3<-\gamma_1<-m$. That is, $\chi_1(-m^{1/3}) <0$.

Just in case, here is a couple of inequalities equivalent to the one in question:
$$\gamma_2(\alpha_1^3+m)+\gamma_1(\alpha_2^3+n)<0,$$
$$(\frac{\gamma_1}{\alpha_1^3}+1)(\frac{\gamma_2}{\alpha_2^3}+1) > 1.$$